# How to make a border animation for a block with a small height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an animated border for a button. But this only works if the button is tall. For a low button, it works strangely. As you can see in the example, the second button, which has a height of `200px`, works fine, but the first one doesn't. How can I fix this and **use this animation for a button with a height of** `40px`?

```css
.button {
  width: 172px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.button:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 200px
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: #002b53;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: conic-gradient(transparent 20%, #fff 20%, transparent 30%);
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: Start by eliminating the background color on the ::after pseudo - that should give you a good idea, of _why_ it behaves "strange" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially rotating the colored background box, the box's dimensions didn't match the necessary and exposed blank parts, so you just have to scale the box with `transform: scale();`

In your case the rotation cancels out with the scale so it has to be included in the animation (it still remains static thought).
You can also achieve some interesting effects if you make the scale change with the animation aswell.

Just editing the width or height would move the background.

#### One caveat

Its speed seems irregular, that's because the thinner part of the gradient is visible, I think you can fix this by moving the background up and down using @keyframes (in the same animation) or making it in a different way all together, but I'll leave that up to you.

**Here's the solution:**

```css
.button {
    width: 172px;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.button:nth-child(2){
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 200px;
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #002b53;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-image: conic-gradient(transparent 20%, #fff 20%, transparent 30%);
    animation: rotate 8s linear infinite;
}

.button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0) scale(3)
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn) scale(3);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is not perfect: its animation is not uniform because of the different distance between center of button and sides.

```css
.button {
  width: 172px;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.button:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 200px
}    
.button:nth-child(3){
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  width:60px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity:.5;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg);
  width: 1000%;
  height: 1000%;
  background-color: #002b53;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: conic-gradient(transparent 20%, #fff 20%, transparent 30%);
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
/*    transform: rotate(0deg); */
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the smooth border animation, there are 4 span elements that will be needed. All span will be positioned as absolute of the parent (Here Button).

you can achieve this by using the below code for any height and width you want.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  margin: 28px auto 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  filter: hue-rotate(340deg);
  border: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #071952;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4, 0 0 25px #03e9f4, 0 0 50px #03e9f4, 0 0 200px #03e9f4;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.btn span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: animate1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.btn span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: animate2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.btn span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: animate3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.50s;
}

@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.btn span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: animate4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

.btn-2 {
  height: 40px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.btn-3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  Submit
</button>

<button class="btn btn-2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  Submit
</button>

<button class="btn btn-3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  Submit
</button>
```